# Django Custom error page's giving error

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-errors

I'm trying to make custom error page general 404 and 500.

I'm not trying to raise just making a default if it happens for a user, but every place I'm trying to search and follows a tutorial and so on I always ends up in getting an internal error on both 500 and 404

I'm running django=1.11.6, and I'm running debug False because I need to see if it work of course.

How can I fix this issue and make it work?
And how can I make it so it also gives the user the error text so they can send it to me?

#### Views.py (In my app folder)

```
# Error Handlers
def handler404(request):
    return render(request, 'handlers/404.html', status=404)

def handler500(request):
    return render(request, 'handlers/500.html', status=500)
```

#### Urls.py (in my main config folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, handler404, handler500
from django.contrib import admin

handler404 = 'staff.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'staff.views.handler500'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('staff.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need custom handlers if you just want to use your own templates - just put your own 404.html and 500.html files in your root templates directory.

Secondly, rather than getting users to send you the error codes manually, you can configure Django to [send you errors by email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/error-reporting/).